# Android WebView is not showing animations on Websites

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, android-jetpack-compose, android-webview

I am trying to create an app from this website (https://pithydigital.com/) using WebView. I didn't encounter any problem while using WebView with other websites. But for this website when I try app can not show the animations(lottie files) used on website. By the way everything is working fine when I enter the website using Google Chrome. Here is my code :

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            WebsiteTestTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Greeting()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting() {
    val url = "https://pithydigital.com/"

    val loaderDialogScreen = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    if (loaderDialogScreen.value) {

        Dialog(onDismissRequest = {
            loaderDialogScreen.value = false
        },
            properties = DialogProperties(
                usePlatformDefaultWidth = false
            )
        ) {
        }
    }

    AndroidView(factory = {
        WebView(it).apply {
            layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            )
            settings.javaScriptEnabled = true

            settings.mixedContentMode = 0

            settings.userAgentString = System.getProperty("http.agent")

            webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)

                    loaderDialogScreen.value = true
                }
                override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url)

                    loaderDialogScreen.value = false
                }
            }

            loadUrl(url)
        }
    },
        update = {
            it.loadUrl(url)
        })
}
```

And this is my AndroidManifest file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.WebsiteTest"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|keyboardHidden"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.WebsiteTest">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks in advance.